# How to install a mobile template in apache cordova 6.1.0

Tags: javascript, android, apache, cordova

So I am running Apache Cordova on Ubuntu trying to create a multi-platform hybrid application. So far I am done with the steps of:

- Installing Codova
- Assigning the Andoird Home, configuring the sdk and the avd
- Being able to export the project on the browser and as an apk file
- Testing the apk file and making sure it's working fine on a real device 
  After unzipping the mobile template written in (HTML/CSS/JS) into the application's directory and removing the default index.html to make sure the full files of the templates are functional, everything seem to be working fine.

The question is, is this normally how it should work? or is there something that I have to do within the cordova's app directory's default files (like the default index.html) in order to not miss with the installed cordova plugins like (camera, geolocation .... etc) ?

In other words, do I treat the cordova's app's www directory just like I treat a regular website files on a server, or are there other steps?

Comment: Yes, that is the right way and if there is no very special reason, don't modify the files in the platform folders.

Comment: You can replace the whole www content with your own. You'll have to link cordova.js in your index.html if you want to use cordova features (don't look for it, it will be created and copied to the right place when you run the app)